# Getting a segmentation fault after a thread completes it's job

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_n(int);

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_t thread;

        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, print_n(100), NULL))
        {
            printf("pthread_create error\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void *print_n(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return NULL;
}
```

This is an example program aiming to illustrate the problem. I get a segmentation fault after the second time `pthread_create` is called, but don't know why.

Comment: Turn on all your compiler warnings...

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I suppose you mean compiling with ```-Wall```. I did, but I got no additional warnings.

Comment: Add `-pedantic -Wextra` if you're using GCC.  You have a simple, subtle error that's really hard to see and it's going to be blindingly obvious once you see it.  Welcome to C programming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your invocation of `pthread_create` is not what you expect.  Specifically, the third parameter `print_n(100)` is evaluating the result of calling the function, not passing a pointer to the function to be called by the created thread.  Thus, you see "100" printed once as the function is evaluated, then its return value `NULL` is passed to `pthread_create`, which then dereferences `NULL` when starting the thread causing the seg fault.  So it is actually the first invocation of `pthread_create` that is failing, not the second.

Also note that if you want to pass an argument into the function, you do so by using the 4th parameter to `pthread_create`.  This means when you want to pass 100 to the new thread's function, you need to do so as a `void*` that the function `print_n` then needs to handle appropriately.  And the function must take a `void*` as its argument, not some other type like `int` as you have.

One final thing to know: creating so many threads in a tight loop as you have exhausts thread pool resources (at least on my platform) returning the error message "Resource temporarily unavailable".  You can see that by checking `errno` on `pthread_create` failure.

Here is your code I modified to take into account everything I said:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *print_n(void*);

int main()
{
    int arg = 100;
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_t thread;

        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, print_n, &arg))
        {
            printf("pthread_create error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void *print_n(void *n)
{
    int *arg = (int*)n;
    printf("%d\n", *arg);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> don't know why.

Because your program is calling `NULL`.

The function `print_n(100)` returns `return NULL;` always. So:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, print_n(100), NULL);
```

is equivalent to:

```
print_n(100);
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This starts a separate thread that calls `NULL`. When this thread receives processor time, it dereferences `NULL` by calling a function there. So your program receives `segmentation fault`, because it's tries to read data from a protected area, dereference `NULL` in this case.

Funny, that there is no check if the function passed to `pthread_create` is `NULL`.